# How to view files stored under root?

Tags: ssh, terminal

I have been able to successfully create a root folder and store documents there.  How can i be able to view whats there using SSH? What commands do i have to use? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ls` is the command, `/` refers to the system root. So go with `ls /`

Answer (score 1):

`ls` lists files if the remote is a Unix host. `man ls` explains how it works (in a rather terse way).

Answer (score 1):

Go with `ls`.

from any folder: `ls /path/to/folder`

from within folder: `ls`